# CSV header styling in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm using [this](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/csv/rdoc/) to export records to CSV format. But i want to give styles to headers.

Here is my .erb

```
<%= CSV.generate_line(["X"+"\t"+"Y"+"\t"+"Y"+"\t"+"T"]).html_safe %>
<%@coupons.each do |coupon|%>
    <%= CSV.generate_line([coupon.x+"\t"+coupon.y+"\t"+coupon.z+"\t"+coupon.t]).html_safe %>
<%end%>
```

How can i give styles to headers or columns? At least i want to make them bold:)

Thnaks.

Comment: Your code (correctly) says CSV but you keep calling it CVS (which is something [totally different](http://cvs.nongnu.org/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is a plain text format so you cannot add styles to it.

Comment: i know but my client is displaying cvs in excel for example. Im just wondering if i can give style to headers.

Comment: No, as mfdoran says, CSV is a plain text format so you can't add styles to it. If you want an Excel document (which *can* have styles added to it) then that's not a CSV any more

Answer (score 0):

To use styles, formatting, charts etc you will need to generate an ecma-376 (eg excel) or odf file. If you are on RoR, you might have a look at this:

http://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx